# Core Graphics button. Best practice please

Tags: ios, button, swift, core-graphics

I have now learned to add core graphics as subviews. Looks gorgeous and 2x independent. 
I haven't found a tutorial on Core Graphics Button with action for Swift. First thing that came in mind is that I simply draw graphics and then make transparent buttons on top of them, but I am sure it is not the correct way and I want to change some button design properties based on events, like ifpressed ifloggedin etc.

What would be the standard or best practice on doing custom core graphics as buttons in Swift. Any code examples welcome. Thank you!

Comment: btw, I am using iDraw to design custom vector shapes and export them as core graphics code. Sketch app also does it. This workflow saves a lot of time and I can focus on design. These are cheap compared to bigname vector graphics software and allows a designer transition towards ios app design.

Answer (score 2):

subclass UIButton and provide a custom drawRect implementation

Comment: Daij-Djan, sorry for asking, but I would be grateful for a workflow, like - create a new file choosing this, make an instance of a class, override this and that, copy code here, now drawrect and finally do this. Or if you would provide a code sample, it also would be great. Thank you.